# Selenium IDE - Inserting New Command

Tags: selenium-ide

In Selenium IDE, while inserting New Command, do I have specify details for CSS and XPath for every link or button I select?

Please help me understand how I can insert commands manually in Selenium IDE using FireBug.

Comment: It is unclear what your are asking, please revise your question.

Comment: this is two questions in one.  the first question is answerable, the second one is not.. please do as @CMate asked and revise your second question

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer:

> No.

## Long Answer:

No, you don't need to "just" specify a CSS or Xpath selector.  You have [other options](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#locating-elements) like

- [Identifier](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#locating-by-identifier)
- [ID](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#locating-by-id)
- [Name](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#locating-by-name)
- [Link text](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text)